# Отобразить ссылку из WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно чтобы из `<WebBrowser Source="google.ru"/>` `Source` отобразился в `Lable`

сам код

XML

```
WebBrowser x:Name="browser" Margin="0,27,0,0"/>
```

C#

`browser.Source = new Uri("google.ru");`

```
Lable.Content = browser.Source.ToString();
```

пробовал и так

```
Lable.Content = browser.Source.OriganalString;
```

Но это не работает.

Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поиск по английскому стеку привёл вот к такому [вопрос-ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263551/databind-the-source-property-of-the-webbrowser-in-wpf).

Если кратко — WebBrowser.Source не является DependencyProperty, и не может быть получен из XAML. Требуется написать хелпер, который будет выполнять всю «грязную работу».

В комментариях есть ещё решения, одно из которых я и адаптировал для вашего случая:

1. создаём HtmlBox.xaml

> ```
> <UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>                    x:Class="Web.HtmlBox">   <WebBrowser x:Name="innerBrowser"
>               Margin="2,2,2,2"/>
> </UserControl>
> ```

2. В связанном HtmlBox.xaml.cs пишем следующее:

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Windows;
> using System.Windows.Controls;
>
> namespace Web {
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Interaction logic for HtmlBox.xaml
>     /// </summary>
>     public partial class HtmlBox : UserControl {
>         public HtmlBox() {
>             InitializeComponent();
>         }
>
>         public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlUriProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HtmlUri",
>             typeof (Uri), typeof (HtmlBox));
>
>         public Uri HtmlUri {
>             get { return (Uri) GetValue(HtmlUriProperty); }
>             set { SetValue(HtmlUriProperty, value); }
>         }
>
>         protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
>             base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
>             if (e.Property == HtmlUriProperty) {
>                 DoBrowse();
>             }
>         }
>
>         private void DoBrowse() {
>             if (HtmlUri != null) {
>                 innerBrowser.Source = HtmlUri;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

3. после этого в нашем main.xaml можно написать так:

> ```
> <Window x:Class="MainNamespace.MainWindow"
>         ...
>         xmlns:web="clr-namespace:Web">
> ...
>                 <web:HtmlBox x:Name="browser" HtmlUri="http://google.com"/>
>                 <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,2,2" Content="{Binding ElementName=browser, Path=HtmlUri.OriginalString}"/>
> ...
> </Window>
> ```

4. PROFIT

Comment: Почему то он не видит "innerBrowser" говорит что не существует в текущем контексте

Comment: Проверьте декларации классов, они должны быть в тех же пространствах имён. См. XAML: <UserControl ... x:Class="**Web**.HtmlBox">, cs: namespace **Web** { public partial class HtmlBox: UserControl {...

Comment: Это на месте <UserControl ... x:Class="Web.HtmlBox"> cs: namespace Web { public partial class HtmlBox: UserControl {... всё перепроверил

Comment: всё разобрался у меня namespace по другому называется в проекте

Comment: Теперь он ругается на <WpfApplication2:HtmlBox

Comment: В вашем главном XAML надо добавить в самом начале (где объявляются namespace'ы строчку <Window x:Class=... xmlns:web="clr-namespace: **Web**" ...>, вместо Web подставить ваш неймспейс. Скорректировал свой ответ заодно...

Comment: член HtmlUri не распознан или не доступен.

Comment: Проверьте уровень доступа для Web.HtmlBox.HtmlUri, должен быть public (файл HtmlBox.xaml.cs)

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28928/discussion-between--and-norritt).